# List Does Not Equal When It Should

Tags: c#

I have an Object called `User`. Here's my class:

```
public class User
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string IdNumber { get; set; }
  public string OrgName { get; set; }
  public string AcctCode { get; set; }
}
```

I create TWO objects that are exactly the same.

I want to see if their Equal, however, I get `False` back.

```
User user1 = new User()
{
  Name = "Test User",
  IdNumber = "1000354",
  OrgName = "North",
  AcctCode = "FTW"
};

User user2 = new User()
{
  Name = "Test User",
  IdNumber = "1000354",
  OrgName = "North",
  AcctCode = "FTW"
};

var doesEqual = user1.Equals(user2);
Console.WriteLine(doesEqual); // Returns FALSE
```

I also have TWO lists that have same objects in them, except for one.

When I do the `Except`, it doesn't want to work right and returns 131.

```
List<User> ListOne; // Contains 131 User objects
List<User> ListTwo; // Contains 130 User objects
var difference = ListOne.Except(ListTwo);
Console.WriteLine(difference); // Returns 131
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

By default, `reference types` will compare references.  Meaning that your 2 separate instances, even though their fields have the same value, are different object and will compare as inequal.  You can change this behavior by having your class implement `IEquatable<T>` to "teach" it how to compare any way you want.

A great example, that almost matches your usage, can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Class default equality criteria is by reference. It should return false.

You can override `Equals` method (and then you will have to implement `GetHashCode`) to whatever logic you want.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{    

    if(!(obj is User)) 
    {
        return false;
    }

     User user= obj as User;
    return user.Name == Name && user.IdNumber == IdNumber && user.OrgName == OrgName && user.AcctCode == AcctCode;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return IdNumber.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that all the properties of your objects have the same value, they are two completely different object. This `user1` holds a reference to the heap for an object with some values. The same holds for `user2`. That being said this are two different references to the heap.

If you don't override the `Equals` method, then the equality is based on the references. So the objects are different, even when they have exactly the same values for all of their properties.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equal because `User` is a *class* (i.e. a "reference type").  For reference types, `.Equals` compares *reference equality*, and the two instances `user1` and `user2` are two separate references.

Comment: See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) about the `Object.Equals` method.  When comparing value types `int`, `bool`, `long`, et cetera, `Object.Equals` will perform as you expect.

Comment: @BenM -- Thanks, but that's irrelevant.  The OP is comparing reference types, not value types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
user1.Equals(user2)
```

This line is asking if the user1 object the same as the user2 object. They have the same values but they are not the same object in memory. If you want to compare the values of these two objects you can override the Equals method like so:

```
public static override Equals(User user2)
{
    return (this.Name == user2.Name &&
            this.IdNumber == user2.IdNumber &&
            this.AcctCode == user2.AcctCode &&
            this.OrgName == user2.OrgName) 
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach -- it's very brittle as any future updater of the class will have to remember to modify this method to accommodate any changes.

Comment: make sure you do it right:  
"It is recommended that any class that overrides Equals also override System.Object.GetHashCode."  
[Guidelines for Overloading Equals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Your class User does not implement anything to tell the runtime when two objects are equal. The simpliest way to acchieve this is by overwriting the two Methods Equals and GetHashCode like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{    
    User other = obj as User;
    if( other == null ) return false;
    return other.Name == Name && other.IdNumber == IdNumber && other.OrgName == OrgName && other.AcctCode == AcctCode;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return IdNumber.GetHashCode();
}
```